# If cell value starts with a letter

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to make this GOTO ZPLUS when this cell starts with the letter K.  I want it to Goto ZPLUS for example for this value "K89188" in column A. Because it starts with the letter K.  In fact I would like it to GOTO ZPLUS if the value contains any letter.

```
  If Application.Worksheets("RawData").Range("H" & Z) = 1 Or Left("A" & Z, 1) = K Then
    Y = Application.Worksheets("RawData").Range("A" & Z + 1)
    GoTo ZPLUS
  End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
With Application.Worksheets("RawData")
    If .Range("H" & Z).Value = 1 Or .Range("A" & Z).Value Like "[A-Z]*" Then
        Y = .Range("A" & Z + 1).Value
        GoTo ZPLUS
    End If
End With
```